# What is the purpose of the *Async methods in .Net Framework given the ability to run any method asynchronously using Task.Run?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

**Short question:**

Why did .Net Framework add a lot of *Async versions of method instead of developers just using `Task.Run` to run synchronous methods asynchronously?

**Detailed question:**

- I understand the concept of asynchronisity.
- I know about `Tasks`
- I know about the async/await keywords.
- I know what *Async methods in .Net Framework do.

What I don't understand is the purpose of the *Async methods in the library.

Suppose that you have two lines of code:

```
F1();
F2();
```

With respect to the data/control flow there are only two cases:

- `F2` need to be executed after `F1` finishes.
- `F2` does not need to wait for `F1` to finish.

I don't see any other cases. I don't see any general need to know the concrete thread that executes some function (apart from UI). The base execution mode of code in a thread is synchronous. The parallelism requires multiple threads. The asynchronisity is based on parallelism and code reordering. But the base is still synchronous.

The difference does not matter when the `F1`'s workload is small. But when A takes a lot of time to finish, we may need to look at the situation and, if `F2` does not need to wait for `F1` to finish, we can run `F1` in parallel with `F2`.

Long time ago we did that using threads/thread pools. Now we have `Tasks`.

If we want to run `F1` and `F2` in parallel, we can write:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(F1);
F2();
```

tasks are cool and we can use `await` in places where we finally need the task to be finished.

So far, I don't see any need to make an `F1Async()` method.

Now, let's look at some special cases.
The only real special case I see is UI. The UI thread is special and stalling it makes the UI freeze which is bad.
As I see it, Microsoft advices us to mark the UI event handlers `async`. Marking the methods `async` means that we can use the `await` keyword to basically schedule the heavy processing on another thread and free the UI thread until the processing is finished.

What I don't get again is why do we need any *Async methods to be able to await them. We can always just write `await Task.Run(F1);`. Why would we need `F1Async`?

You may say that the *Async methods use some special magic (like handling external signals) that make them more efficient than their synchronous counterparts. The thing is that I don't see this beeing the case.

Let's look at the `Stream.ReadAsync` for example. If you look at the source code, `ReadAsync` just wastes several hundred lines of bells and whistles code to create a task that just calls the synchronous `Read` method. Why do we need it then? Why not just use `Task.Run` with `Stream.Read`?

This is why I don't understand the need to bloat the libraries by creating the trivial *Async copies of synchronous methods. MS could have even added the syntactic sugar, so that we could write `await async Stream.Read` instead of `await Stream.ReadAsync` or `Task.Run(Stream.Read)`.

Now you may ask "Why not make the *Async methods the only ones and remove the synchronous methods?". As I've said earlier, the base code execution mode is synchronous. It's easy to run synchronous method asynchronously, but not the other way.

**So, what is the purpose of the *Async methods in .Net Framework given the ability to run any method asynchronously using Task.Run?**

P.S. If the non-freezing the UI is so important, why not just run the handlers async by default and prevent any chance of freezing?

**The "no threads" argument:**

People answering this question seem to imply that the advantage of *Async methods is that they are efficient because they don't create new threads. The problem is that I don't see such behavior. The parallel asynchronous tasks behave just like I thought - a thread is created (or taken from the thread pool) for each parallel task (not all tasks are executed in parallel though).

Here is my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication32167 {
    class Program {
        static async Task TestAsync() {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20) };

            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select((i) =>
                httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/SlowWebsite/"));

            Console.WriteLine("Threads before completion: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Threads after completion: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Threads at start: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);

            var timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();

            var testTask = TestAsync();

            var distinctThreadIds = new HashSet<int>();
            while (!testTask.IsCompleted) {
                var threadIds = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.OfType<ProcessThread>().Select(thread => thread.Id).ToList();
                distinctThreadIds.UnionWith(threadIds);
                Console.WriteLine("Current thread count: {0}; Cumulative thread count: {1}.", threadIds.Count, distinctThreadIds.Count);
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }

            testTask.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This code tries to run 100 `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` tasks making requests to a website that takes 1 minute to respond. At the same time it counts the number of active threads and the cumulative number of different created by the process. As I've predicted, this program creates many new threads. The output looks like this:

```
Current thread count: 4; Cumulative thread count: 4.
....
Current thread count: 25; Cumulative thread count: 25.
....
Current thread count: 7; Cumulative thread count: 63.
Current thread count: 9; Cumulative thread count: 65.
00:10:01.9981006
```

This means that:

- 61 new threads are created during the course of the async task execution.
- The peak number of new active threads is 21.
- <strike>The execution takes 10x more time (10 minutes instead of 1).</strike>*This was caused by the local IIS limits.*

Comment: @Arkkun, I voted to close your question because of the wording like *... need to pollute the libraries by creating the trivial *Async copies of synchronous methods...*

Comment: @Noseratio is "bloat" ok, or does are the connotations too negative?

Comment: Reworded the question as "What is the purpose of the *Async methods in .Net Framework given the ability to run any method asynchronously using Task.Run?"

Comment: You may want to change this part too: *As an example the Socket class in Windows Phone 7 version of .Net only has *Async methods. Calling them synchronously requires some very ugly and error-prone code.* You can use `async/await` on WP7 too with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, and have a beautiful code. I guess it was just an overall impression that you were taking the naturally-async concept so negatively only because you didn't have a good understanding of it. Hopefully, @StephenCleary's answer has changed your perception. I now voted to reopen your question.

Comment: You need to understand what _non-blocking IO_ means and why.  (eg, Node.js)

Comment: @Noseratio I've removed the part about the WP7. What I meant by "ugly code" was code like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20260936/1497385 also suggested by Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202864%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_SendingDatatoaUDPSocketServer

Comment: @Arkkun, such code can be greatly improved with `TaskCompletionSource`, which turns a future event (EAP pattern) into a `Task`, or with `FromAsync`, which turns Begin/End/callback-style API (APM pattern) into a `Task`. Then you can simply `await` the task. There are many answers here on SO illustrating this, just search for EAP/APM/TAP keywords.

Comment: @SLaks I get the general idea. But what I see with the concrete .Net 4.5.1 is that using `await` with -Async methods like `FileStream.ReadAsync` and `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` causes many new threads to be created. Isn't creating new threads for the tasks the opposite of the idea of the *non-blocking IO*?

Comment: That should not be true.

Comment: @SLaks I've added the code that demonstrates many threads being created while waiting for `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` tasks to finish.

Comment: @Ark-kun, the pool threads are used to handle the *completion* of the naturally async operation. That's why you may see the pool growing. The IO completion code handler *has* to be called on some thread, other than the thread currently executing your code. The point is, while the asynchronous operation still *is pending* ("in flight"), it doesn't occupy and block any threads, so the vacant threads can be used for other useful work. That's especially important for server-side code handling multiple requests.

Comment: @Ark-kun: No.  While the IO is happening, no threads are consumed at all.  Obviously, your completion code (which is not non-blocking) must run on some thread; it runs on an IO completion port.

Comment: @SLaks >"While the IO is happening, no threads are consumed at all." What does "consumed" mean? Are my process' threads that wait for IO completion "consumed".

Comment: @Noseratio >"The IO completion code handler has to be called on some thread" "while the asynchronous operation still is pending ("in flight"), it doesn't occupy and block any threads" - As you see, my "completion" code is basically non-existent. The thread count grows while the asynchronous operations are "in flight".

Comment: @Noseratio Am I correct? Basically, you're saying that the only advantage/magic of the *Async methods is that running their payloads does not require having specific corresponding threads in the caller's process. That way I could run 10000 long-running Async methods **in parallel** using only, say, 10 thread or less. While this would explain the purpose of the Async methods and answer my question, I fail to see this happening. Can you provide some proof of concept code that is able to demonstrate the reduced thread usage while running parallel Async methods? My code showed the opposite.

Comment: @Ark-kun, here's a very easy proof of concept: `await Task.Delay(1000)`. Compare it to `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))`. Feel free to post this case as a separate question, I'm sure it will be popular :)

Comment: @Noseratio `Task.Delay` is not an "*Async" method. I want to see some real Async method in work.

Comment: @Ark-kun, `Task.Delay` is as much async as `HttpClient.GetStringAsync`. You don't have to argue if you doubt this. Rather, I encourage you to post it as a new question, just pick some nice wording. This one is apparently not going to get re-opened, anyway.

Comment: @Noseratio `Task.Delay` empirically has thread economy (isn't it, in the end, just a record in a scheduler table inside Windows?). Neither of the *Async methods that I've tried has thread economy. That's the empirical difference.

Comment: @Noseratio Another difference is that `Task.Delay` doesn't have any workload. It cannot be "in flight". I've looked at the code: `Task.Delay` uses `System.Threading.Timer` which in turn is scheduled via a single (per AppDomain) `System.Threading.TimerQueue`. That's why it only uses a single thread.

Comment: @Ark-kun: Here's a more complicated example, but it should prove the question well. Create a simple web application that accepts a request and then delays for, say, a minute, before returning a response. Now run a client application that hits the web application's endpoint using `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` 100 times. If the method is using the thread pool, you'll either see 100 threads created, or you won't get through all 100 calls for minutes. If not, the calls should all complete immediately, and if you `await Task.WhenAll()` it should take roughly 1 minute to complete.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I did the same, basically. But you're right - it's better to use a controlled response website instead of a just a random slow website. I will test it right now. As for the thread pool, I think that you're wrong. As I observed, when tasks use thread pool, they only use about 9-10 threads.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I've done the test that you've suggested (making 100 requests to a local website that waits for 1 minute). The results are very telling. The test took 10 minutes (10 times more). Through the run, +61 new threads were summarily started - up to +21 of them active at the same time. The magic failed to materialize - 10x slowdown while using a lot of threads.

Comment: @SLaks I've just run a more rigorous test. `GetStringAsync` was **10 times slower** (10 minutes instead of 1) and caused **61 new threads** to be created. Right now it looks like the practical results are quite different from the theoretical estimates.

Comment: @Ark-kun, my mileage is different: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21717514/1768303

Comment: Dear downvoters. TL/DR doesn't mean downvote.

Answer (score 16):

> Marking the methods async means that we can use the await keyword to basically schedule the heavy processing on another thread and free the UI thread until the processing is finished.

That's not at all how `async` works. See my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

> You may say that the *Async methods use some special magic (like handling external signals) that make them more efficient than their synchronous counterparts. The thing is that I don't see this beeing the case.

In pure asynchronous code, [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) (as I explain on my blog). In fact, at the device driver level, *all* (non-trivial) I/O is asynchronous. It is the synchronous APIs (at the OS level) that are an abstraction layer over the natural, asynchronous APIs.

> Let's look at the Stream.ReadAsync for example.

`Stream` is an unusual case. As a base class, it has to prevent breaking changes as much as possible. So, when they added the virtual `ReadAsync` method, they had to add a default implementation. This implementation has to use a non-ideal implementation (`Task.Run`), which is unfortunate. In an ideal world, `ReadAsync` would be (or call) an abstract asynchronous implementation, but that would break every existing implementation of `Stream`.

For a more proper example, compare the difference between `WebClient` and `HttpClient`.

Comment: >"That's not at all how async works. See my async intro." I've read that precise blog entry before asking my question >_< "The "async" keyword enables the "await" keyword in that method. That's all the async keyword does!" "If "await" sees that the awaitable has not completed, then it acts asynchronously. It tells the awaitable to run the remainder of the method when it completes, and then returns from the async method." "the awaitable will capture the current "context" and later apply it to the remainder of the async method" - that's what I meant.

Comment: >"there is no thread" I'd argue that every code instruction runs on some thread. Am I wrong?

Comment: >"For a more proper example, compare the difference between WebClient and HttpClient" I'll look at them.

Comment: @Ark-kun: The main point about "That's all the async keyword does" is that it specifically does *not* offload operations to a background thread. Regarding "there is no thread", the point is that asynchronous operations do not execute code, hence there is no thread required to run them. E.g., if you do a `ReadAsync` on a file opened for asynchronous access, then that I/O does not block a thread while the read is being done; it just sets up the transfer buffers, starts the read operation, and returns. Whereas a `Read` wrapped in `Task.Run` does block a thread.

Comment: >"it specifically does not offload operations to a background thread" Yes, I understand that.

Comment: >"asynchronous operations do not execute code, hence there is no thread". `var result = await stream.ReadAsync(...); int continuationThreadId = AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();`

Comment: >"Stream is an unusual case" Ok. I looked at `FileStream`. At first it seemed that it just calls the synchronous `ReadFile` from kernel32.dll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx But then I saw the OVERLAPPED structure. Looks like `FileStream.ReadAsync` has some magic after all.

Comment: @Ark-kun: I still don't get it. You say you understand that `async` does not offload operations to a background thread; but the entire point behind your question is asking why we don't use `Task.Run` wrappers around synchronous methods. I'll try to put it a different way: A (correct/ideal) `*Async` method does not block a thread regardless of the number of operations; a `Task.Run` wrapper around a synchronous method *always* blocks a thread for each operation.

Comment: >"a Task.Run wrapper around a synchronous method always blocks a thread for each operation." What thread does it block? AFAIK, it returns immediately. Did you mean to say that `Task.Run` uses thread pool? What about `TaskFactory.StartNew(F1)` which uses `TaskScheduler`?

Comment: I've investigated the `HttpClient.SendAsync`. It seems to call `Task.Factory.StartNew(httpClientHandler.StartRequest, state);`. I'll need to investigate other methods.

Comment: `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` both use the thread pool, and if you use them to call a synchronous method, they will block a thread pool thread. Most `*Async` library methods end up calling `TaskFactory.FromAsync` or `TaskCompletionSource`, which do not block a thread pool thread.

Comment: I've tried to `Task.WaitAll` 100 calls to `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` like you in your blog entry (`DoOperationsInParallelAsync`). It created many threads (not 100, but many). When I called the `FileStream.ReadAsync` 10 threads were started and I clearly saw (in a stack trace) that the ThreadPool was used to run the payloads.

Comment: Again `Stream` and friends are unusual. You have to be sure to open the file explicitly for asynchronous access.

Comment: But what about `HttpClient.GetStringAsync`? Ok, I've found the constructor that lets me open the `FileStream` for async IO (it seems a bit stupid to no use async IO in the explicitly asynchronous method like `FileStream.ReadAsync` (I'm talking about `FileStream`, not `Stream`) ). Now the ThreadPool is not used and the behavior is similar to `HttpClient.GetStringAsync`. Many new threads are started. I see it in the Task Manager and in the Visual Studio Threads window.

Comment: This is a very enlightening discussion, guys. I never would have thought that a file stream's async method wouldn't be truly asynchronous unless the object was created with a specific constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Let's do the realistic test: naturally asynchronous [`WebRequest.GetResponseAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) vs unnaturally synchronous [`WebRequest.GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First, we extend the standard limits of the `ThreadPool`:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MAX_REQS * 2, MAX_REQS * 2);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(MAX_REQS, MAX_REQS);
```

Note I request the same number of `workerThreads` and `completionPortThreads`. Then we'll perform `MAX_REQS` = 200 parallel requests to bing.com, using each API.

**The code** (a standalone console app):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace Console_21690385
{
    class Program
    {
        const int MAX_REQS = 200;

        // implement GetStringAsync
        static async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url)
        {
            using (var response = await WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }

        // test using GetStringAsync
        static async Task TestWithGetStringAsync()
        {
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, MAX_REQS).Select((i) =>
                GetStringAsync("http://www.bing.com/search?q=item1=" + i));

            Console.WriteLine("Threads before completion: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Threads after completion: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
        }

        // implement GetStringSync
        static string GetStringSync(string url)
        {
            using (var response = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        // test using GetStringSync
        static async Task TestWithGetStringSync()
        {
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, MAX_REQS).Select((i) =>
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => GetStringSync("http://www.bing.com/search?q=item1=" + i),
                    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Default));

            Console.WriteLine("Threads before completion: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Threads after completion: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
        }

        // run either of the tests
        static void RunTest(Func<Task> runTest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Threads at start: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);

            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            var testTask = runTest();

            while (!testTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Currently threads: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Threads at end: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count + ", time: " + stopWatch.Elapsed);

            testTask.Wait();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MAX_REQS * 2, MAX_REQS * 2);
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(MAX_REQS, MAX_REQS);

            Console.WriteLine("Testing using GetStringAsync");
            RunTest(TestWithGetStringAsync);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Testing using GetStringSync");
            RunTest(TestWithGetStringSync);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Testing using GetStringAsync
Threads at start: 3
Threads before completion: 3
Currently threads: 25
Currently threads: 84
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 84
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 84
Currently threads: 84
Currently threads: 84
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 84
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 82
Currently threads: 82
Currently threads: 82
Currently threads: 83
Currently threads: 25
Currently threads: 25
Currently threads: 26
Currently threads: 25
Currently threads: 25
Currently threads: 25
Currently threads: 23
Currently threads: 23
Currently threads: 24
Currently threads: 20
Currently threads: 20
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 18
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 18
Currently threads: 18
Currently threads: 18
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 18
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 19
Currently threads: 18
Currently threads: 18
Currently threads: 17
Threads after completion: 17
Threads at end: 17, time: 00:00:51.2605879

Testing using GetStringSync
Threads at start: 15
Threads before completion: 15
Currently threads: 55
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 213
Currently threads: 212
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 210
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 209
Currently threads: 205
Currently threads: 201
Currently threads: 196
Currently threads: 190
Currently threads: 186
Currently threads: 182
Threads after completion: 178
Threads at end: 173, time: 00:00:47.2603652
```

**The result:**

Both tests takes about 50 seconds to complete, but `GetStringAsync` peaks at 83 threads, while `GetStringSync` does at 213. The higher the `MAX_REQS` figure goes, the more threads are wasted by the blocking `WebRequest.GetResponse` API.

@Ark-kun, I hope you see the point now.

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly consistent with my results. I.e. `Through the run, +61 new threads were summarily started - up to +21 of them active at the same time.`. Thanks for independently validating the number. So, what are you trying to say with this number?

Comment: I focused on the other aspects: First, 61 **different** new threads for 100 tasks defeats the "thread economy" argument. Second, 10x slowdown defeats the "optimization/efficiency" argument.

Comment: I've updated my code using your code + cumulative thread counting. But that's not all. You need a slow operation (slow website) to really see the problem. I've set up a website like that locally.

Comment: Ok. 10x slowdown is caused by IIS (10 concurrent connections on a client machine). I'll remove part about the slowdown from the question. But the fact that 60 new threads may be created for 100 tasks is still there.

Comment: Right now my vision is like this (well it was like that since the beginning): *Async `Task`s still use some sort of thread pool. When there is some code that needs executed, the pool grows (new threads are created). When the pool idles, it shrinks (threads are terminated). That's OK by me - I'm not a "no threads" purist. Shrinking and growing the pool causes the cumulative thread count to grow.

Comment: @Ark-kun, check the update. I expect you'll find another argument, but please read about [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) first.

Comment: You expected wrong =) In this journey I've finally seen the not-too-bright glimpse of the famous Async magic. (Previously, I couldn't see the "magic" clearly, because the IIS bottleneck made it look no different than a 10-thread sequential threadpool.) I'll sleep on this new information and try to summarize everything the next day.